# Create whitelist in mobile hotspot windows 10 and only allow device in whitelist

Tags: windows, windows-10, hotspot

In windows 10, there is a feature call Mobile Hotspot. I already can share internet through mobile hotspot. Does windows 10 mobile hotspot have feature like whitelist device and i also want only device in whitelist can connect to my mobile hotspot.